# swift firebase how to set/add data at the top of database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an app that incorporates Firebase and need to be able to be able to add/and or set data at the top of the my database. Currently whenever I add data it places it randomly under the parent node. I've seen some **Objective C** answers to this but they haven't really made to much sense. Sorry for the lack of code, but I don't know where exactly where to start on this issue. Any help would be great!

Comment: Yes, at the top of the parent node it is under

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say it is getting placed 'randomly' under the parent, I think this is the `childByAutoId()` method getting called. While the name of the nodes appears randomly (e.g. `-K6tdghsbci7g8`), it will actually ensure that data is added under  a given parent node in order. This is very useful for adding new data to lists. For example:

```
let pointlessData:String = "some data"
ref.childByAutoId().setValue(pointlessData)
// creates a new ordered child node under the `ref` with "some data" as the value
```

There isn't really a way to order the nodes back to front in this fashion, although you could order negatively by timestamp by adding a negative timestamp to each node you add then order your results using `ref.queryOrderedByChild("negativeTimestamp")` such that the values you get are the newest first.

Answer (score 1):

```
let path = FirebaseBaseUrl + "dialogs/" + self.receiverId + "/" + self.senderId

    let chilRef = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL(path)
    let refChild = chilRef.childByAutoId()
    let dic = NSMutableDictionary()
    dic .setValue(text, forKey: "text")
    dic .setValue(FIRServerValue.timestamp(), forKey: "timestamp")
    dic .setValue(true, forKey: "your")

    refChild.updateChildValues(dic as [NSObject : AnyObject]) { (error, ref) in
        if(error != nil){
            print("Error",error)
        }else{
            print("\n\n\n\n\nAdded successfully...")
        }
    }
```